# Any polynomial function is continuous - what about a constant function?

Tags: general-topology

I read that any polynomial function is continuous. I.e. If we have an open set $U$ in the range, $f^{-1}(U)$ will be open in the domain.

Let $\mathbb{R}$ have the standard topology.

Define $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that

$x \to a_0 + a_1x + a_2x^2 + ... + a_nx^n$

Well what if we have, say, $f(x) = 1$

And we take the open set $U = (4, 5)$ in the range. There is no $f^{-1}(x)$ in this case so how can we find an open set in the domain that lets us say $f$ is continuous?

Comment: If $f$ is constant, then $f^{-1}(U)$ is either $\varnothing$, which is open, or $\mathbb{R}$, which is also open. We don't even need an open $U$ for that.

Comment: What do you mean by 'either'? What would make $f^{-1}(U) = \emptyset$ as opposed to $f^{-1}(U) = \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Let $f(x) \equiv c$. Then either $c\in U$ or $c\notin U$. That's what decides whether the preimage is empty or the entire space.

Comment: $f^{-1}[U] = \{x \in X: f(x) \in U \}$ by definition. It is allowed to be empty or $X$ or anything in between. The definition of continuity just says then when $U$ is open, so must the set $f^{-1}[U]$ be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your example the set $f^{-1}[U] = \emptyset$ is open in $\mathbb R$. In general, for a constant $f$, only two possibilities can occur: $f^{-1}[U] = \mathbb R$ and $f^{-1}[U] = \emptyset$. Both are open. Hence constant functions are continuous.